# Javascript Insert into Array

Tags: php, javascript

I have  javascript code some thing like this --

```
var count=3;
var pl=new Array(count);
var il=new Array(count); 

pl.push('<?php echo $var1; ?>');
il.push('<?php echo $var2; ?>');
```

Why is this not working?

But if I try some thing like this

```
pl[0]='<?php echo $var1; ?>';
```

It works. Can some one point out the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You're aware where PHP runs, and where Javascript runs? Explain how / from where your "javascript code" is delivered, not just what it contains.

Comment: Also, please define "doesn't work". Both of those should work, but have wildly different results. `pl.push(10)` results in `[undefined, undefined, undefined, 10]`; while `pl[0] = 10` results in `[10, undefined, undefined]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using the `Array` constructor you are creating an array with a number of "slots" already defined. In your case, the arrays both have 3 elements when you create them (the value of each element is `undefined`.)

When you use `push`, you add an *extra* element to that array. When you set the element at a specific index, you just set the value of that element.

I would suggest not using the `Array` constructor, and instead creating array literals:

```
var pl = [];
var il = [];
pl.push('<?php echo $var1; ?>');
il.push('<?php echo $var2; ?>');
```

This time, the arrays are created with no elements, so when you use `push` you are pushing an element into index 0, instead of 4.

Comment: Thank You for providing the explanation too. My code is working .. :)

Comment: This isn't safe; @anttihaapala's is correct. And shorter and quicker to run.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var pl=[];
var il=[]; 
pl.push('<?php echo $var1; ?>');
il.push('<?php echo $var2; ?>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `new Array(count)` creates a new `Array` object with `length` set to `count`, but no indices set. When you print the array, you get `array.length` times `undefined`. Now,

```
array.push(value);
```

is the same as

```
array[array.length] = value;
array.length ++;
```

Which after `new Array(3)` would set the element number 3 (the 4th element);

```
pl[0] = '<?php echo $var1; ?>';
pl[1] = '<?php echo $var2; ?>';
pl[2] = '<?php echo $var3; ?>';
```

does work "correctly"; that is according to the expectations; but you still do not need to initialize the length of array; even doing

```
var pl = [];
pl[0] = 1;
pl[1] = 2;
pl[2] = 3;
```

Would still cause the `pl.length` to be 3.

---

However your PHP code has a serious flaw that can undermine the security of both your website and the users using it. If `$var1` contains a `'` character (because it comes from the user or you insert it by accident), you will shoot yourself in the foot - say if `$var1` was set to:

```
$var1 = "'; $.ajax('/user/delete', { method: 'post' }); '"
```

Please do yourself a favor and use the `json_encode` function instead to properly quote the values:

```
var pl = [],
    il = []; 
pl.push(<?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>);
il.push(<?php echo json_encode($var2); ?>);
```

or even better notice that you can use the `json_encode` to readily create arrays, as

```
var pl = <?php echo json_encode(array(1, 'a', 'b', 5.7)) ?>;
```

This would produce JavaScript code:

```
var pl = [1,"a","b",5.7];
```

---

You must be careful with the unicode characters U+2028 and U+2029, as these are [proper JSON but not proper JavaScript](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset). `json_encode` does seem to encode them as `\u2028` and `\u2029` which is safe.